# C# While loop skipping virst line when parsing csv

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

I have a simple CSV file I need to parse that has variable column lengths. [CSV File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12u0u_h4J_TdxHwJapDyRYwJqkDJiOxeur0kBBJt5iaE) for reference.

I'm attempting to write some conditions to parse each line and store into a discreet string based off what value the first column contains in each line.

The first issue that I'm running into is that my loop seems to start reading at row 2. Is this because TextFieldParser assumes a header?

The second issue is that my if statements don't seem to be evaluating correctly. If I shift the order of the rows within the file, my first if in the order is supposed to parse the "Lighting" rows (regardless of which rows in the file contain "Lighting").

*Just as a note, I am working in a .net 3.5 environment*

Here's what I've got so far:

```
namespace CSV_Handler_Console
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Press Enter");

            string filePath  = "C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\ConfigFile.csv";



            string subLight = "Lighting";
            string subPin = "PIN";
            string subProc = "Processor";
            string subFab = "Fabuloso";
            string subQuirky = "Quirky";

            //string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
            string category = string.Empty;
            string index = string.Empty;
            string load1 = string.Empty;
            string load2 = string.Empty;
            string load3 = string.Empty;
            string load4 = string.Empty;
            string value = string.Empty;

            string light1 = string.Empty;
            string light2 = string.Empty;
            string light3 = string.Empty;
            string pin = string.Empty;
            string processor1 = string.Empty;
            string processor2 = string.Empty;
            string processor3 = string.Empty;
            string processor4 = string.Empty;
            string processor5 = string.Empty;
            string processor6 = string.Empty;
            string processor7 = string.Empty;
            string processor8 = string.Empty;
            string display1 = string.Empty;
            string display2 = string.Empty;
            string display3 = string.Empty;
            string display4 = string.Empty;
            string display5 = string.Empty;
            string display6 = string.Empty;
            string display7 = string.Empty;
            string display8 = string.Empty;


            var path = String.Format("{0}", filePath);

            using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
            {

                csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                //csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;

                string row = csvParser.ReadLine();

                while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
                {                   
                        if (row.Contains(subLight))
                        {
                            string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();

                            category = fields[0];
                            index = fields[1];
                            load1 = fields[2];
                            load2 = fields[3];
                            load3 = fields[4];
                            load4 = fields[5];

                            if(index.Contains("1"))
                            {
                                light1 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("2"))
                            {
                                light2 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("3"))
                            {
                                light3 = row;
                            }

                            string rowData = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", category, index, load1, load2, load3, load4);
                            Console.WriteLine(rowData);
                            //Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        else if (row.Contains(subPin))
                        {
                            string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();

                            category = fields[0];
                            index = fields[1];
                            value = fields[2];
                            string rowData = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", category, index, value);
                            Console.WriteLine(rowData);
                        }
                        else if (row.Contains(subProc))
                        {
                            string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();


                            category = fields[0];
                            index = fields[1];
                            value = fields[2];

                            if (index.Contains("A"))
                            {
                                processor1 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("B"))
                            {
                                processor2 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("C"))
                            {
                                processor3 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("D"))
                            {
                                processor4 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("E"))
                            {
                                processor5 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("F"))
                            {
                                processor6 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("G"))
                            {
                                processor7 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("H"))
                            {
                                processor8 = row;
                            }
                            string rowData = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", category, index, value);
                            Console.WriteLine(rowData);
                        }
                        else if (row.Contains(subQuirky) || row.Contains(subFab))
                        {
                            string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();


                            category = fields[0];
                            index = fields[1];
                            value = fields[2];

                            if (index.Contains("A"))
                            {
                                display1 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("B"))
                            {
                                display2 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("C"))
                            {
                                display3 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("D"))
                            {
                                display4 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("E"))
                            {
                                display5 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("F"))
                            {
                                display6 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("G"))
                            {
                                display7 = row;
                            }
                            else if (index.Contains("H"))
                            {
                                display8 = row;
                            }
                            string rowData = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", category, index, value);
                            Console.WriteLine(rowData);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("No Match Found");
                        }
                    }

                Console.ReadLine();

                }
        }

}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Just the opposite.  You are displaying "No Match Found" because the header is not matching any of the IF statement in the code.

Comment: That initial readLine is moving the cursor to the second row.

Comment: Just as a clarification, this file does not contain a header. I also made an edit to my post before I saw your comments, not sure if it would lend any more info or not.

Comment: @RickMcDonald I was afraid that might be the case. What would a better way to initialize my "row" string without advancing to the next line? In other words, I need data in the string to evaluate, but I don't know how to assign the string without calling ReadLine() to get it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your implementation. You first grab the first row with ReadLine, which advances the cursor to the next line. Then if the row contains your search property, you do a ReadFields, which is the 2nd line of the document.

If your data is always guaranteed to have the category, you could just use ReadFields and compare against the first element. You could look at PeekChars if you want to look at the content of the current row without advancing the cursor.

> TextFieldParser.ReadLine: Returns the current line as a string and
>   advances the cursor to the next line.
>
> TextFieldParser.ReadFields: Reads all fields on the current line,
>   returns them as an array of strings, and advances the cursor to the
>   next line containing data.
>
> TextFieldParser.PeekChars: Reads the specified number of characters without advancing the cursor.

Comment: That makes sense actually. Should I to my ReadLine() at the beginning of the while loop and simply peek during my if statements?

Comment: If you can guarantee the first column (Category) is always populated, I would just use  ReadFields. I'll update the answer with some suggestions

Comment: I changed to:                 

while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
                    string toCheck = fields[0];

                    if (fields[0].Contains(subLight))
                    {

Etc. etc, and that worked- thank you!

Comment: Perfect. Also note that you can re-use your existing row based assignment by simply doing: string row = string.Join(",", fields); after setting the fields array.

Comment: @bradleyfitz Thats make sense. Basically once row data is part of `fields` then business logic should be driven based on `fields`.